# Extract information from a column in csv which is formatted as JSON

Tags: r, json

I have a csv file which the column is formatted as JSON file:

```
{
  matching_rules: [
    {
      id: 1028, 
      id_str: 102,
      tag: 213ee072
    }
  ], 
  profilelocations: [
    {
      address: {
        country: United States, 
        countrycode: E, 
        locality: null, 
        region: Rhode Island, 
        subregion: null
      }, 
      geo: { 
        coordinates: [
          -978, 
          4
        ], 
        type: point
      }, 
      objecttype: place
    }
  ], 
  urls: null
}
```

I want to get only tag as a new column with the relevant value of tag. 
could you please let me  know how I can get the tag and its value as a new column in R. 
What I have done so far is as follows: 
step1: remove all the strings after profilelocations:

```
s<-gsub("profilelocations.*","",newraw1)
```

and remove the string before tag: using :

```
s1<-gsub(".*tag:","",s)
```

Then I should try to remove the }] to get the only tag:

```
s2<-gsub("[^0-9A-Za-z///' ]","" , s1,ignore.case = TRUE)
```

but i do not like this way to get the tag with its values.

Comment: That's not valid JSON, each of the keys will need quotes (`""`) around them, and the non-numeric values too.

Comment: I tried df1<-gsub("id","\"id\"",newraw$gnip) for id but I have id_str then all the ids got "" like follows: "id" , "id"_str which is not correct. do you have any idea

Comment: Where does the data come from? There may be a better way to extract the data, rather than try and format it.

Comment: The data comes from AWS Athena

Comment: I also removed the unnecessary data after tag as following:newraw1<-gsub("profilelocations.*","",newraw1)

Comment: please edit your question with all these extra steps you've done. It's also helpful if your question is reproducible. Use `dput(newraw[1, ])` to output the first row of your data and add that to your question.

Comment: Sure I am editing now

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
newraw1 <- "{
  matching_rules: [
    {
      id: 1028, 
      id_str: 102,
      tag: 213ee072
    }
  ], 
  profilelocations: [
    {
      address: {
        country: United States, 
        countrycode: E, 
        locality: null, 
        region: Rhode Island, 
        subregion: null
      }, 
      geo: { 
        coordinates: [
          -978, 
          4
        ], 
        type: point
      }, 
      objecttype: place
    }
  ], 
  urls: null
}"

sub("\n.*", "", sub(".*tag: ", "", newraw1))

# [1] "213ee072"
```